# SQLite query row issue in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, relational-database

I'm having an issue with getting specific rows with a Cursor in Android. This is my set up. I have multiple rows in one table (~38000) (Geolocation) and about 300 in the other one (Availability).

Geolocation looks like this: _ID LATSTART LONSTART LATEND LONEND
Availability looks like this: ID MONTH_START MONTH_END DAY_START DAY_END PROHIBITTED_START PROHIBITTED_END PAID_START PAID_END

Geolocation stores start and end geopoints, availability stores time ranges
They have a one-to-many relationship

The program draws different colored lines based on the location of the line and the time
My problem is that I am running three different queries (prohibited, free, paid), each one is overlapping though.

Here's my query for prohibited rows

```
            prohibQuery = "SELECT * " + 
                      "FROM " +
                           "AVAILABILITY AS A JOIN (      SELECT * " +
                            "FROM GEOLOCATION " +
                            "WHERE ABS(LATSTART - (?) + LONSTART - (?)) < 2.3E-4 " +
                       "OR ABS(LATEND - (?) + LONEND - (?)) < 2.3E-4) AS G ON A.GEO_ID = G._ID " +
                      "WHERE (?) BETWEEN A.MONTH_START AND A.MONTH_END AND (?) BETWEEN A.DAY_START AND A.DAY_END " +
                        "AND A.PROHIB_START <= (?) AND A.PROHIB_END > (?) ";
```

Here's my code for "free" rows, the problem is that I will have two lines on the same exact spot with overlapping colors, so it won't be green or red, it will be whatever combo that is (not an artist).

```
            Cursor mCursor = sqliteDb
            .rawQuery(
                    "SELECT * "
                            + "FROM GEOLOCATION, " +
                            prohibQuery +
                            "AS PROHIB "
                            + "JOIN AVAILABILITY ON GEOLOCATION._ID=AVAILABILITY.GEO_ID "
                            + "WHERE "
                            + "((abs(LATSTART - (?)) + abs(LONSTART - (?))<2.3E-3) OR (abs(LATEND - (?)) + abs(LONEND - (?))<2.3E-3)) AND "
                            + "((?) BETWEEN MONTH_START AND MONTH_END) AND ((?) BETWEEN DAY_START AND DAY_END) AND "
                            + "((?)<PROHIB_START OR PROHIB_END<=(?)) GROUP BY GEO_ID "
                            + "AND GEOLOCATION._ID <> PROHIB.ID"
```

By the way, the variables I didn't include, they're just current values (i.e.:location, month, day, hour)
Here are some row examples.

The rows are related ON GEOLOCATION._ID=AVAILABILITY.GEO_ID.

```
_ID     NAME    LATSTART      LONSTART      LATEND        LONEND
2691    Alpine  45.477741   -73.655335  45.4763953  -73.6522115
2692    Alpine  45.4748043  -73.6486557 45.4762943  -73.652106
2693    Alpine  45.4744849  -73.6478719 45.4748043  -73.6486557
2694    Alpine  45.4741615  -73.6471631 45.4744849  -73.6478719
2695    Alpine  45.4738386  -73.6464376 45.4741615  -73.6471631
2696    Alpine  45.4743872  -73.6459077 45.4738386  -73.6464376
2697    Alpine  45.4743945  -73.645721  45.4743872  -73.6459077
2698    Alpine  45.4738146  -73.6444395 45.4743945  -73.645721


ID       START   END    START END PROHIBSTART END PAIDSTART END GEO_ID
-38146  0   11  1   7   3   6   0   0   2691
-38155  0   11  1   7   9   17  0   0   2691
-38147  0   11  1   7   3   6   0   0   2692
-38148  0   11  1   7   3   6   0   0   2693
-38149  0   11  1   7   3   6   0   0   2694
-38150  0   11  1   7   3   6   0   0   2695
-38151  0   11  1   7   3   6   0   0   2696
-38156  0   11  1   7   0   24  0   0   2697
-38153  0   11  1   7   0   24  0   0   2698
-38154  0   11  1   7   0   24  0   0   2699
```

Comment: I have a line being drawn, represented by the Geolocation table, the row is being duplicated and being drawn twice once it joins with the availability table. It either draws the same color or different colors. I have three methods which are supposed to grab different types of rows. One grabs red, the 2nd grabs green and third - blue. I need to have it so there is no overlap between the methods. The red one draws when current time is between prohib interval, and green when it isn't. Ex: if there are two interval rows for one street, one might draw red and the other green.